# How can I generate combinations from given string value in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have cell value www_2_w4_14 for that I want to get all the combination like www, www_2, www_2_w4, www_2_w4_14. I have tried combinations of SPLIT, ARRAYFORMULA, JOIN, SUBSTITUTE functions but it doesn't seems to be working for me.

I tried below formulas but no success so far.

```
1> =LEFT(A2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","")))))

2> =ArrayFormula(JOIN(",",ArrayFormula(LEFT(SPLIT(A2,"_")&"",SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",""))+1,1)))))
```

What I want is www, www_2, www_2_w4, www_2_w4_14

Answer (score 2):

You need `SCAN()` function.

```
 =SCAN("",TOCOL(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|_"),"|")),LAMBDA(a,x,a&x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works in Excel, hopefully also in Sheets (can't test unfortunately):

`=LET(ζ,A1&"_",TEXTBEFORE(ζ,"_",SEQUENCE(LEN(ζ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(ζ,"_","")))))`

Comment: I don't think textbefore is available in Google Sheets yet but a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that OP's original formula (1>) is basically OK and can be made to work as follows:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(s,A2&"_",LEFT(S,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(s,"_","@",sequence(1,LEN(s)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(S,"_","")))))-1)))
```

[image]

Similar logic to @Jos Woolley's answer - no lambda required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"_","(?:.*?_){"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,"_")))&"}"),"_$",))
```

Or

```
=SCAN(,SPLIT(A1,"_"),LAMBDA(a,c,REGEXREPLACE(a&"_"&c,"^_",)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but here's one more approach:

```
=let(Σ,split(A1,"_"),
    makearray(1,counta(Σ),lambda(r,c,join("_",array_constrain(Σ,1,c)))))
```

[image]